# JSON Data Iteration with a List of Results

Tags: python, json, flask, jinja2

I am new to python and attempting to iterate over a list of results that I am getting back from an BDMS API. The results are formatted like so:

```
{
  "results": [
    "\"Metadata\"\n",
    "\"Metadata\"\n",
    "\"Metadata\"\n",
    "\"Metadata\"\n",
    "\"Metadata\"\n",
    "\"Metadata\"\n",
    "\"Metadata\"\n",
    "\"Metadata\"\n",
    "\"Metadata\"\n",
    "\"Metadata\"\n",
    "\"Metadata\"\n",
    "\"Metadata\"\n",
    "\"Metadata\"\n",
    "\"cs295\"\n"
  ]
}
```

**How would I use Flask and Jinja to produce me a lists of Metadata and cs295?**

My python code is below:

```
response = requests.get(query_url, headers=http_header)
j = json.loads(response.text) # JSON response back
return render_template('builder.html', response=j)
```

and HTML bit:

```
{% for i in response.items() %}
<h1>Value: {{ i }}</h1>
{% endfor %}
```

The result is just my input, and not a list of Metadata and cs295.

Comment: Try it without the parentheses after items:
`{% for i in response.items %}`. And actually, I think it would be a dictionary, so it should likely be `{% for k, v in response.items %}`.  Not sure. Unfamiliar with flask and jinja2

Comment: @bozdoz I think you are right. Key value pair, which will give me access to v. Then from that point, another iteration to access each item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can think of `response.items()` returns a list of tuples, each tuple containing a key and the corresponding value for that key in the dictionary.

In your case, you probably don't want to use `response.items()` and instead want to do:

```
{% for value in response['results'] %}
    <h1>Value: {{ value }}</h1>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This did it! Now my results are "Metadata"'s and "cs295."